# how to show 7 days backdate in Date Picker in Android

Tags: android, date

I have two `datepicker` `From` and `to`
i want to have today's Date in to
and 7 Days back Date in From 
for example today date is  `01/10/2012` it should be in `to` while seven days back date i.e `23/9/2012` should be in `From`

What i have done is, i am able to get date today's date but how can i get date 7 days back 
what i have done is

```
Calendar ToDateCal=Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener td=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year,int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
            ToDateCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            ToDateCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            ToDateCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateToDate();
        }
    };


private void updateToDate(){
    try{
    int iDay;
    int iMonth;
    int iYear;

    iDay=ToDateCal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    iMonth=ToDateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    iMonth=iMonth+1;
    iYear=ToDateCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    String sTDate=iDay+"/"+iMonth+"/"+iYear;
    ToDate.setText(sTDate);
}
    catch(Exception ex){
        sResponse=ex.toString();
    }
}
```

Click Events on Edittext

```
        ToDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                new DatePickerDialog(DRSTClaimPage.this,td,ToDateCal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                ToDateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH),ToDateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
```

and to set the Date

```
   FromDate.setText(dt.getStDt());

public String getStDt(){
    return ((dt.getDate())+"/"+(dt.getMonth()+1)+"/"+(dt.getYear()+1900));

}
```

Like This
[image]

Comment: It is unclear for us where you exactly wanted to have date before 7 days,in your code. what is the flow of what you want to achieve?

Comment: on my EdittText do u want to have a image of that

Comment: no..image is not required. but just explain the way,how you want it to work? i mean,when user chooses a date and what would you like to do with that? EditText are just part of datepicker itself,right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you:

```
Calendar currDate=Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar weekBackDate=Calendar.getInstance();
weekBackDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-7);
```

**EDIT :**

Looking to your question closely,i think,you want to set text in your FromDate,date before 7 days. Then you can use above code like this:

```
    private void updateToDate(){
        try{
        int iDay;
        int iMonth;
        int iYear;

        iDay=ToDateCal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        iMonth=ToDateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        iMonth=iMonth+1;
        iYear=ToDateCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        String sTDate=iDay+"/"+iMonth+"/"+iYear;
        ToDate.setText(sTDate);

        setFromDate();
    }
        catch(Exception ex){
            sResponse=ex.toString();
        }
    }

private void setFromDate(){

     FromDate.setText(String.format("%1$td / %1$tm / %1$tY",ToDateCal));
}
```

Comment: in which function i need to declare this

Comment: actually i didn't get what exactly you want to know..like-you would like to know how to set this date in date picker or you want to use date somewhere else once you have it from date picker?

Comment: i want to show in datepicker and then in use it inj next page

Comment: I have Edited a image i hope now u understand